# raven not reporting exceptions to sentry

Tags: python, django, wsgi, sentry, raven

Uncaught exceptions are not being reported to sentry.

I have ran `manage.py raven test` and I get the test message in sentry to confirm the communication is working.

My configurations include:

```
# settings.py

RAVEN_CONFIG = {
    'dsn': '****',
}

SENTRY_CLIENT = 'raven.contrib.django.raven_compat.DjangoClient'

SENTRY_AUTO_LOG_STACKS = True

INSTALLED_APPS += [
    'raven.contrib.django.raven_compat',
]
```

then

```
# wsgi.py

from raven.contrib.django.raven_compat.models import client

client.captureException()
```

Answer (score 4):

As shown in the [docs](http://raven.readthedocs.org/en/latest/usage.html), you should call `client.captureException()` when there is an exception:

```
try:
    1 / 0
except ZeroDivisionError:
    client.captureException()
```

In `wsgi.py` you [should do](https://docs.getsentry.com/hosted/clients/python/integrations/django/#wsgi-middleware) this instead:

```
from raven.contrib.django.raven_compat.middleware.wsgi import Sentry
from django.core.handlers.wsgi import WSGIHandler

application = Sentry(WSGIHandler()
```

Answer (score 0):

First thing You need to hardcode your DSN as it contain importante information, 
then on django i think it's better to work with python **logging**

```
RAVEN_CONFIG = {
'dsn': os.environ.get('SENTRY_DSN'),
}

 LOGGING = {
'version': 1,
'disable_existing_loggers': False,
'formatters': {
    'verbose': {
        'format': '%(levelname)s [%(pathname)s:%(lineno)d] - %(message)s'
    },
    'simple': {
        'format': '%(levelname)s %(message)s'
    },
},
'handlers': {
    'sentry': {
        'level': 'ERROR',
        'class': 'raven.contrib.django.raven_compat.handlers.SentryHandler',
        'tags': {'custom-tag': os.environ.get('SENTRY_TAG')},
    },
    'console': {
        'level': 'ERROR',
        'class': 'logging.StreamHandler',
        'formatter': 'verbose'
    }
},
'loggers': {
    'django': {
        'handlers': ['console', 'sentry'],
        'level': 'ERROR',
    },
    'Your_app {
        'handlers': ['console', 'sentry'],
        'level': 'ERROR',
    },
    'raven': {
        'level': 'ERROR',
        'handlers': ['sentry', 'console'],
        'propagate': False,
    }

}
}
```

then run python manage.py raven test and share the console message